# How can I fix compile errors?

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}


\declaretheoremstyle[
  title=Доказательство,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  qed=\blacksquare
]{myproof}
\declaretheorem[style=myproof, numbered=no]{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    this is a simple proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This code is based on thmtools documentation. I can read produced errors, but I have no idea of syntax, which can fix them. Thanks in advance

EDIT

I have added these lines:

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and now I only have 4 errors:

[image: errors2]

Comment: For my humble opinion it is a problem of font encoding for russian babel.

Comment: You didn't declazre any font encoding, so you're sopposed to use the default: OT1, which is OK only  for english.

Comment: as the (first) error tells you proof is already defined.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't just use `amsthm` with two redefinitions: `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\blacksquare}` and `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Доказательство}`?  That should work without needing `thmtools`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I would like to use thmtools, because it's much easier for me to customize it's commands

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes, I see that, but i don't know what to do about it, except calling my proof environment smth like proof2, which is meh

Comment: @Bernard, do you mean that thmtools "title=blabla" should not be used with russian symbols?

Comment: I only mean  you should load the T2A font encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thmtools doesn't like to redefine an existing theorem. I don't see anything in the docu about it (but didn't look very hard), but you could simply undefine proof first:

```
\documentclass[13pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, thmtools}


\declaretheoremstyle[
  title=Доказательство,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  qed=$\blacksquare$ %mathmode
]{myproof}

\let\proof\undefined
\declaretheorem[style=myproof, numbered=no]{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    this is a simple proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly works.  The downside is that the ability to use `\qedhere` is lost.  Restoring it isn't trivial.  Calling the new version instead `Proof` would allow use of both.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for mentioning. Where we may need to use the command \qedhere?

Comment: @barbarabeeton \qedhere still works (but I have no idea if it works in all cases and in the same way)

Comment: @Allok -- `thmtools` has apparently implemented `\qedhere`; I didn't think it had.  As for where `\qedhere` is useful, it's intended to be used to move the tombstone up to the last line when a proof ends with a display equation, a list, or other element that isn't simply ordinary text.  See the `amsthm` user guide for examples (`texdoc amsthdoc`).

Comment: thanks to all of you